# how to create an aws lambda function from a file uploaded in s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, terraform

I have uploaded a zip file to a `private aws s3 bucket`, which has the following contents:

## zipped filename: 'data.zip'

```
__init__.py
lambda_handler.py (where 'handler' is the name of the function)
data.zip (same zip file as the parent)
```

now i want to create a `terraform` `aws lambda function`:

## the way the s3 bucket was created

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket_for_lambda" {
  bucket = "bucket-for-lambda"
  acl    = "private"

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }

  versioning {
    enabled = true
  }

  server_side_encryption_configuration {
    rule {
        apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
          sse_algorithm = "AES256"
        }
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "iam_policy_lambda" {
  name        = "iam-policy-lambda"

  policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${aws_s3_bucket.bucket_for_lambda.arn}/*"
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}
```

After creating the bucket i have uploaded the zipped filed above manually to the bucket using `aws cli`.

Now when i try to create a lambda function:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_test" {
  function_name       = "lambda-test"

  s3_bucket           = aws_s3_bucket.bucket_for_lambda.id
  s3_key              = "data.zip"
  role                = aws_iam_role.iam_role_for_lambda.arn
  depends_on          = [aws_iam_role.iam_role_for_lambda]
  handler             = "lambda_handler.handler"
  runtime             = "python3.7"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "iam_role_for_lambda" {
  name = "iam-role-for-lambda"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "lambda_policy_attachment" {
  policy_arn  = aws_iam_policy.iam_policy_lambda.arn
  role        = aws_iam_role.iam_role_for_lambda.name
}
```

I know the lambda codes above does not track changes with `source_code_hash`,and that is not creating an `aws lambda layer` nor creating `aws_s3_bucket_object` so terraform can take care of uploading the file but what i want to understand is why, with the simple configuration above, i am seeing this error when i do `terraform apply` (which does not return anything wrong) but afterwards when i want to apply the changes by typing `yes`:

```
aws_lambda_function.merchant_tracker_version_one: Creating...
╷
│ Error: error creating Lambda Function (1): ValidationException: 
│   status code: 400, request id: SOME-ID
│ 
│   with aws_lambda_function.lambda_test,
│   on main.tf line 994, in resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_test":
│  994: resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_test" {
```

Any help would be much appreciated, i already spent two hours trying to google or stackoverflow the solution... still failing!

Comment: Can you provide the full error and also which line here in main.tf is line number 994 in your code?

Comment: You allowed only access to __objects__. You did not allow __access to the bucket__. Add `s3:ListBucket` permission for the bucket where the zip file is located.

Comment: Also, you are referencing the wrong ARN in the part of the policy for getting/putting the objects: `aws_s3_bucket.iam_policy_lambda.arn`. This is a policy ARN. You need the bucket ARN: `aws_s3_bucket.bucket_for_lambda.arn`.

Comment: @MarkoE sorry about the typo above `aws_s3_bucket.bucket_for_lambda.arn` i updated the section above but in the codebase it was actually correct, just changing the names in stackoverflow messed up....besides, i tried to add `s3:ListBucket`..still failing

Comment: @Ashwini this is line `994` in the code base `resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_test" {...` thats where the lambda function code start

Comment: @cu__007 where is the change in the question? Unless I know what was added I can't say if it was a good change or not.

Comment: @MarkoE i implemented `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57145037/how-to-configure-terraform-to-upload-zip-file-to-s3-bucket-and-then-deploy-t` this solution and it seem to work